# JS - Escrever uma função que retorna a maior STRING

Tags: javascript

1. Escrever uma função que retorna a maior string dada.

exemplo:

**entrada:**
"StackOverflow" "Sem resposta" "Tags"

**saída:**

"StackOverflow" // *string com o maior numero de caracters.*

Comment: o que vc já fez para tentar chegar á isso? Mostre seu código se possível

Comment: As vezes uma simples busca no google retorna a resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Você não precisa escrever uma função que já existe, use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var strings = ["StackOverflow", "Sem resposta", "Tags"];
var retorno = strings.reduce(function (atual, proximo) {
  return atual.length > proximo.length ? atual : proximo;
});
alert(retorno);
```